# Long streaming spark time window causing "grows beyond 64 KB" exception

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I have a streaming Spark dataframe with time window of an hour which triggers every minute.

```
val momentumDataAggQuery = withTime
  .selectExpr("parsed.symbol", "parsed.bid", "parsed.ask", "event_time")
  .withWatermark("event_time", "5 seconds")
  .groupBy(col("symbol"), window(col("event_time"), "60 minutes", "60 seconds")) 
  .agg(first("bid", true).as("first_bid"), first("ask").as("first_ask"), last("bid").as("last_bid"), last("ask").as("last_ask"))
```

When it run it throws an exception out with the following error:

```
org.codehaus.janino.InternalCompilerException: Compiling "GeneratedClass": Code of method "expand_doCon
sume_0$(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1;Lor
g/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/InternalRow;Lorg/apache/spark/unsafe/types/UTF8String;ZDZDZJZ)V" of class "
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1" grows beyon
d 64 KB
```

I experimented with reducing the time window and the longest possible that I can use is 30 minutes.

I found relevant jira issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18091 but it looks like there is no solution for now.

Has anyone seen this before? What's the workaround?

Comment: In this case you can try with an UDAF, in that case you would have to create the window manually.

Comment: What's the version of Spark? It looks like a bug in Spark and the only solution is to somehow come up with an alternate query to avoid running into the bug.

Comment: it's running on Spark 2.3.1

Comment: Any updates on this ? I'm running into the same issue when my F.when is too long, due to successive conditions.